# c++ how to initialize open file dialog (GetOpenFileName)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mingw

my code is as follows.

```
OPENFILENAMEA open;
ZeroMemory(&open, sizeof(open));

open.lStructSize = sizeof(LPOPENFILENAMEA);
open.lpstrFilter = "Képek\0*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp\0\0";
open.nFileOffset = 1;
open.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
open.nMaxFile = 2048;
open.lpstrTitle = "Képek kiválasztása..";
open.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

OPENFILENAME selected = GetOpenFileName(open);
```

My problem is, that I get the following error when trying to build:
`error: cannot convert 'OPENFILENAME {aka tagOFNA}' to 'LPOPENFILENAMEA {aka tagOFNA*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL GetOpenFileNameA(LPOPENFILENAMEA)'` when I call `GetOpenFileName`

If I call it with the open parameter as a ptr `GetOpenFileName(&open)` I get the following `error: conversion from 'BOOL {aka int}' to non-scalar type 'OPENFILENAME {aka tagOFNA}' requested`

Question: what do?

Comment: A few notes on your implementation: You're using `OPENFILENAMEA` but call `GetOpenFileName` (vs. `GetOpenFileNameA`). Be consistent, and since you're using non-ASCII characters you might as well use the UNICODE versions for both (trailing `W`). Your string literal for `lpstrFilter` has a superfluous NUL terminator. String literals are zero-terminated already, i.e. `"\0"` represents the character array `{ '\0', '\0' }`.

Comment: Thank you! However, I already noticed some of these bugs thanks to our beloved compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetOpenFileName` returns a `BOOL`, not an `OPENFILENAME`.

It will return a non-zero value if it returned by the user selecting a file and clicking "Ok". If they clicked "Cancel", it'll return 0.

If it returns true, it will have modified the contents of your `open` to reflect what the user selected.

So, you usually use it something like:

```
if (GetOpenFileName(&open)) {
    // use open.whatever to get data about the selected file
}
else
   // The user clicked cancel -- typically do nothing.
```

Comment: f**k. this is one of the moments when I feel really stupid. Thank you!

Comment: @19greg96: The primary function of the compiler is to make us all feel like idiots as often as possible. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BOOL selected = GetOpenFileName(&open);
```

I'm not familiar with WinAPI, but check out the error message:

> error: cannot convert 'OPENFILENAME {aka tagOFNA}' to 'LPOPENFILENAMEA {aka tagOFNA*}' for argument '1' to 'BOOL GetOpenFileNameA(LPOPENFILENAMEA)'

means you should pass a pointer to `OPENFILENAME` as argument to `GetOpenFileName`.

> error: conversion from 'BOOL {aka int}' to non-scalar type 'OPENFILENAME {aka tagOFNA}' requested

means the return type of `GetOpenFileName` should be `BOOL`.